# How can I detect if anything in my checkbox is selected?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

If any of the checkboxes are checked, I want to enable the button. Otherwise, if none are checked, I want to disable the button.

**jQuery**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.check_list').change(function() {
    if ($(".check_list input:checkbox:checked").length > 0){
      $(".btn").attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
      $(".btn").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value1">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value2">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value3">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value4">

<button class="btn" disabled> Button</button>
```

It works when I check the button. But when I uncheck everything it is still enabled. But it should be disabled

Comment: I think your if statement is reversed; shouldn't it be if something is checked, enable button, else if nothing is checked disable button?

Comment: do you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/1208/)?

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla The answer of Oriol is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CSS selector is wrong. And use `prop` instead of `attr` unless you know what you are doing.

```js
var $checklist = $('.check_list').change(function() {
  $(".btn").prop('disabled', !$checklist.is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value1">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value2">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value3">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value4">
<button class="btn" disabled> Button</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

There were two issues in your JS code. First one was the selector, and second one, the way you tried to change the disable attribute, where you should have used [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```js
$('.check_list').change(function() {
  if ($('.check_list:checked').length > 0) {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value1">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value2">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value3">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value4">

<button class="btn" disabled> Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to

- Use property (instead of attribute)
- Adjust your selector

See code example below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // init button
  $(".btn").prop('disabled', true);

  $('.check_list').change(function() {
    var numOfCheckedBoxes=0;
    $.each($(".check_list"), function(i, v) {
      
      if ($(v).is(":checked")) {
        numOfCheckedBoxes++;
      }
    });
    
    
    $(".btn").prop('disabled', (numOfCheckedBoxes==0));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value1">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value2">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value3">
<input type="checkbox" class="check_list" name="check_list[]" value="value4">


<button class="btn">Button</button>
```