# How to disable a button in bootstrap for checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a code in java script for disabling a button until the checkbox is checked.  It doesn't grey this out in bootstrap.  It just shows the button.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/soljohnston777/wg00ymg8/
```

Bootstrap attempt to make this work:

Modal / Html:

```
    <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">  
    <div class="modal-header">  
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
    <h3>Terms and Conditions</h3>  
    </div>  
        <div class="modal-body"> 

        <h4>Text in a modal <input type="checkbox" required="required" id="myCheck"></h4>

        <p>You can add some text here.</p> 
    <div class="checkbox">
    <input id="check" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="check">Some Text Here</label>
    </div>          
        </div>  
    <div class="modal-footer">  

    <input type="submit" name="" class="btn" id="btncheck" value="I Agree" />
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Without the Modal classes:

http://www.bootply.com/nV8ShsZUH5

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if anything in my checkbox is selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619257/how-can-i-detect-if-anything-in-my-checkbox-is-selected)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery

Comment: The reason why this isn't a duplicate is because I am having the issue with bootstrap modals.  If the code is run as "not" a modal, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use attributes instead of properties.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Instead of:

```
btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked);
```

You can directly access the disabled attribute from the checkbox object and modify it.

```
this.disabled = !this.checked;
```

Comment: I was aiming for the button to be disabled when the box is not checked. Sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: Edited to remove comments on the part about the logic on the checkbox.

Comment: Could you give me more code to explain.  This problem only happens with the modal is up.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this issue, I had to upgrade to bootstrap 3, then this code worked great

http://www.bootply.com/AlUZOz0zXB